# phpinfo() not working in apache2

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I wanted to install `php5.3` on `ubuntu 14.04`(its not natively available as ubuntu pkg), so I installed each `apache2`, `mysql5.6` and `php5.3` separately.

PHP5.3 is utmost important for my project.

Now i wanted to test if each of them was working fine together.

I created a info.php file in `/var/www/html/` containing code as `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` but the output showed an output like an HTML rendered page.

[image]

Can anyone please tell me how to test/check if all three of them are working together fine?

I would be very thankful, if anyone can please give a link or detailed-description where I can read instructions on how to integrate all three of them together while not uninstalling any of them.

Comment: i had read a question on `http://askubuntu.com/questions/462673/installing-php-5-3-in-ubuntu-14-04` and saw that no one received the answer for that, I googled and got this link `https://stavrovski.net/blog/build-and-install-php-5329-from-source-on-an-ubuntu-1404-lts-server` where it is nicely instructed how to install php5.3. (I couldn't answer on `askubuntu` due to less reputation points there). Kindly some add this link there for the answer. It is working nicely for me, except for the `make test` part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5` if you didnt before.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Though `mysql` info is not shown in phpinfo(). looking through other stackoverflow answers for that now.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu

Comment: I just noticed... it changed my php5.3.29 to php5.5.9 version. :(

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5

This doesn't work because is obsolete:

sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package libapache2-mod-php5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libapache2-mod-php5' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent solution for PHP 7: install `libapache2-mod-php`:

```
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php
```